# Neo4j boolean properties in relations

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Is it a good practice to keep multiple boolean properties on relations and create index on each of them for faster searches based on relation properties?

I have following type of relations structure (almost 50 properties per relation), but wondering if there is other better approach and if this is a best practice at all:

```
MATCH (d:student)-[r:community]-(n) RETURN r LIMIT 1;

  {
  "type": "community",
  "properties": {
  "x": false,
  "y": false,
  "z": false,
  ...
  "k": false,
  "l": false,
  }
 }
```

Doing my first steps in graph databases and not sure if this is the correct way.

P.S. My first idea coming to mind is to join all properties in single string value like:

```
          xyz   kl
 "total":"000...00"
```

But this seems to require a lot of development effort.

Comment: You always have to ask yourself what are the queries going to look like?

Comment: It depends. if X is only the true value, then you can use relationship label like [:COMMUNITY_X].

Comment: but I have >50 properties , shall I make labels like [:community_x_y_z..]?

Comment: 50+ boolean properties seem too much. I would have recommended you, store them in a bit array and index the array. But the indexes on the list aren't very helpful as well. Can you elaborate more on your use case, maybe we can help you in defining your schema?

Comment: Do you have to set property if is false? Can't you take missing property as false and set only true?
I also suggest to take a look at Byte Array.